# Flight enters US before my visa is valid

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I have gotten a non-immigrant visa that starts on August 15. I thought it would start on August 1, and got a flight from Europe to the US for August 4.

What can I do in this situation? I think rebooking the flight will be difficult. Is Visa Waiver an option for the intermediate time?

Comment: Are you eligible for the visa waiver program? If so, why did you apply for a visa? What type of visa is it? Did you tell the US Consulate you planned to travel on August 1 or August 15th? They may be able to correct the visa (reissue it) if they've made a mistake and you contact them.

Comment: I am going to work in the US from August 15 on, that's why I can't use visa waiver for the full time. Yes I am eligible.

Answer (score 1):

The question is based on a wrong premise: my visa is in fact valid from an earlier date.

I was fooled by the "annotation field" in the visa, which states the dates of my program. The person at the embassy I spoke to said that one may enter up to 30 days before and exit up to 30 days after the program.

If someone has the same question but with a correct premise, I'd be happy to open this question again!